# How to hide services from public_api.ts in Angular library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

I'm looking to make a shared Angular (7.2.15) library, and only expose abstract classes I'm using as interfaces in the `public_api.ts`.  However, I keep running into errors saying `Cannot find module './lib/my-module/my.service`.

The reason for this is that I need a singleton service to record events in my library's components, and provide those to the outer application via an `EventEmitter`.  I only want the application itself to have access to the `EventEmitter`, and not the other methods on the service.  So I created my service as such:

my.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService implements AppInterface, LibraryInterface {
  private _events: Subject<string>

  public getEventObservable (): Observable<string> {
    return this._events.asObservable()
  }

  public addEvent (eventCode: string): void {
    this._events.next(eventCode)
  }
}
```

app-interface.ts

```
export abstract class AppInterface {
  public abstract getEventObservable (): Observable<string>
}
```

library-interface.ts

```
export abstract class LibraryInterface {
  public abstract addEvent (eventCode: string): void
}
```

I'm looking to provide the service in modules in my library like so: `{ provide: AppInterface, useClass: MyService }`, `{ provide: LibraryInterface, useClass: MyService }`.  However, if I provide the `AppInterface` in a module exported in `public_api.ts`, it requires me to export both the interface AND the service in `public_api.ts`, otherwise I get the error from the first paragraph.  I only want apps that use my library to be able to import the interface, never the service.

One additional wrinkle I can't seem to get around, if I never provide the `AppInterface` anywhere, and provide the `LibraryInterface` in a module that isn't exported in `public_api.ts`, I still run into the error.  Not sure why it would expect me to provide an internal service that is never exposed to the app...